# Items from last month AND if not possible, items from this month

Tags: postgresql, join, view, greatest-n-per-group

So the title is not really clear, but I could not think how to put it into shorter words better.

My problem is:

I have a database, which I use for web-scraping, with different articles and their prices. The prices may change each month. To be able to have a history, I created two tables:

- `items` which has all articles that are currently in this month's crawling. The table has all the infos on every article
- `log` which has only an `article-id`, `price` and `date`

So basically in `items` every article is unique, while `log` can have multiple occurrences of an article.

What I want to do now: I have created a view which yields every article from `items` and among other things calculates the price difference to last month (as the price and date in `items` is updated each month).

Here's an excerpt from my view:

```
CREATE VIEW XLSX AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT ON(items.article)
           items.article,
           items.price as "price_new",
           ROUND(CAST(items.price - log.price as numeric), 2) as "price_difference",
           log.price as "price_old"
    FROM   items
    INNER JOIN log 
    ON     items.article = log.article
    WHERE  (items.date - log.date) < 25
    ORDER BY items.article, log.date
```

The problem I now have is that new articles are currently not being included in the view. Say for example that at the start of July I have 20 new articles, which are inserted into `items` and `log` with `date = '2017-07-01'`. Obviously they are not included in the view, due to the constraint to only include articles from `log` that are older than 25 days (since the crawler may run periodically multiple times a month, updating the prices more than once).

Could I use `CASE` here to get articles that are older than 25 days or if there are none, get those that have the same date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL ... ON TRUE` to preserve all rows of the right table:

```
SELECT i.article
     , i.price AS price_new
     , ROUND((i.price - l.price)::numeric, 2) AS price_difference
     , l.price AS price_old
FROM   items i
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT price, date
   FROM   log
   WHERE  article = i.article
   AND    date < (i.date - 25)  -- make expression sargable, fix off-by-1 error
   ORDER  BY date DESC          -- to make sure ...
   LIMIT  1                     -- ... we pick at most 1 row
   ) l ON TRUE
ORDER  BY i.article, l.date;
```

Returns ***all*** rows in `items`, and you get `null` for `price_difference` where no previous row older than 25 days is found in `log`.

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

I added `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` to make sure we only pick the one latest entry. If data in table `log` can be trusted to never return more than one row, you can skip the added lines.

Or, if the query does not actually depend on `items.date`, a single subquery depending on the current date using `DISTINCT ON` can be cheaper (with the right indexes):

```
SELECT i.article
     , i.price AS price_new
     , ROUND((i.price - l.price)::numeric, 2) AS price_difference
     , l.price AS price_old
FROM   items i
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (article)
          article, date, price
   FROM   log
   WHERE  date < (CURRENT_DATE - 25)
   ORDER  BY article, date DESC
   ) l USING (article)
ORDER  BY i.article, l.date;
```

About `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. I actually had to change `WHERE date > (i.date - 26)` to `WHERE date < (i.date - 26)`, because I had an error in my OP. Otherwise this worked like a charm and you gave me some useful input on how to structure my queries better!

Comment: @rongon: In this case, to be precise, it should be `WHERE date < (i.date - 25)` - to get the youngest entry "older than 25 days".